# iAds not displayed on app's first screen - ad not loaded

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, iad, lifecycle

I am following [Apple's best practices for iAd](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2264/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011827-CH1-SHARE_ADBANNERVIEW_INSTANCES_ACROSS_VIEWS) in creating a single iAd banner ad object for the whole app in my app delegate - as it says, you should create a single `ADBannerView` and share it across all views. I call the following method to initialize it in my app delegate:

```
- (void)initializeAds {
     // bannerAd is a property of MyAppDelegate
     bannerAd = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     bannerAd.delegate = self;
     bannerAd.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
}
```

And then in my UIViewController, I refer to

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
ADBannerView *myBannerView = appDelegate.bannerAd;
```

This works great in most of my app, running my ad display code for the current UIViewController in `viewDidAppear:`. However, on the first UIViewController (the root UIViewController), when the app is initially opened it does not display an ad. It seems that it hasn't yet loaded an ad. But when I navigate down to another UIViewController, and then go back, the ad is displayed, presumably because it had a chance to load an ad. I am running my test device with a 100% fill rate. How can I force iAd to try to get an ad before my code is run?

Comment: This might be due to Adserver will do  both  connect and disconnect for testing purposes don't worry it is for testing purpose only

Answer (score 0):

In the app delegate, make sure to set the app delegate as the banner ad's delegate. Then, implement the method `-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner`:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    UIViewController *rootViewController = <get the root view controller>;
    [rootViewController displayAds]; // this is the code to display the ad
}
```

When the app first loads, it needs time to load an ad. Internet bandwidth and all that. So when the root view controller is first loaded, the app hasn't had time yet to load any ads. So now the app has time to load an ad, and when that's done, it will display it.